# Куда лучше записывать и потом считывать?

Tags: php

Не могу решить,куда лучше всего записывать кучу строк - **в БД или обычный .txt файл**.Строк может быть от 1 ляма.После записи,необходимо фильтровать их: удалять дубли,фильтр по слову...

P.S - строки - обычные ключевики в 10-20 символов.Их придется иногда чистить от дублей и фильтровать по слову 'скачать',например.Строк будет от 1 миллиона до ...

Comment: в БД... Иначе, если их потом "удалять дубли, фильтровать" - будет больше возни

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу чуть подробнее, пожалуйста. Что за строки, какие операции вы хотите с ними выполнять, и, вероятно, захотите в будущем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от специфики задачи.

Скажем, для работы со списками целочисленных id для одного моего проекта, оказалось гораздо лучше хранить их в бинарных файлах, в двухэтажном дереве папок (для горизонтального масштабирования) безо всяких баз данных. Задачи – экономное хранение, сравнение, сортировка.

Хотя всё это делает MySQL, который я и использовал поначалу, позже выяснилось, что с ростом объёма и нагрузки для моих примитивных задач эффективнее файловое решение, узко заточенное под предсказуемые описанные запросы.

---

> удалять дубли,фильтр по слову

Как вариант, можете строить собственные индексы. Сразу после получения строк, раз пройтись по ним, составив словарь встреченных слов, (корней, или подстрок, если словоформы могут варьироваться и нужен нечёткий поиск), убрать повторы и пр. После этого сможете быстро находить строки (их offset в байтах). Т.е. если задача очень узкая, несложно разработать решение заточенное именно под задачу, оптимизировав всё и вся, и избавившись от целой БД.